# How to use .map to get sting from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

This is my first question because I'm just new to coding.

I want to use .map to get strings from an array.

```js
let root_vegetables = ['potato', 'taro', 'sweet potato', 'carrot']
let trueRoots = root_vegetables.map((roots) => {
    if (roots == 'carrot' && 'sweet potato') {
        return 'True Roots';
    }
    return 'Modified Roots';
})

console.log(trueRoots);
```

so my expected answer is.

```
['Modified Roots', 'Modified Roots', 'True Roots', 'True Roots']
```

Is there Anyways to do this?

Comment: `if (roots == 'carrot' && 'sweet potato')` <- That's wrong; should be `if (roots == 'carrot' || roots == 'sweet potato')`; an `||` (or) statement, since it can't be both.

Comment: your if statement is not correct, should be if (roots == 'carrot' || roots == 'sweet potato')

Comment: try `['carrot', 'sweet potato'].includes(roots)` for your condition.  It's less repetitive, and more easily extensible than `roots == 'carrot' || roots == 'sweet potato'`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your if statement condition is incorrect. You're doing `(roots == 'carrot' && 'sweet potato')`, which won't work because you need to have another condition after the AND operation(`&&`) and not a value as that'll just return true (The statement after the AND, not the if condition)

So you can change `roots == 'carrot' && 'sweet potato'` to `roots == 'carrot' || roots == 'sweet potato'`. Note that we conditon got changed from an AND to an OR condition.

But you can also do:

```
// We use the const keyword instead of let if we don't change the value
// We use true_roots array to do the checking
const true_roots = ['carrot', 'sweet potato']
const root_vegetables = ['potato', 'taro', 'sweet potato', 'carrot']

// We loop through the root_vegetables array and for each value
// we check if its in the true_roots array using the .includes method
// If its included, we return 'True Roots'
// else return 'Modified Roots'
// The code inside the map function is just shorthand/syntactical sugar
const trueRoots = root_vegetables.map((roots) => (true_roots.includes(roots) ? 'True Roots' : 'Modified Roots'))

console.log(trueRoots);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your code almost same, you can also do it like this:

```js
let root_vegetables = ['potato', 'taro', 'sweet potato', 'carrot']
var roots = [];
for (var i = 0; i < root_vegetables.length; i++) {
  roots[i] = 'Modified Roots';
  if (root_vegetables[i] == 'carrot' || root_vegetables[i] == 'sweet potato') {
    roots[i] = 'True Roots'
  }
}
console.log(roots)
```

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, But I need .map to be in my code

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were asking.

```js
let root_vegetables = ['potato', 'taro', 'sweet potato', 'carrot']
let trueRoots = root_vegetables.map((roots) => {
    if (roots == 'carrot' ||  roots =='sweet potato') {
        return 'True Roots';
    }
    return 'Modified Roots';
})

console.log(trueRoots);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this with a single line of code by using `||` operator instead of `&&` along with the ternary operator.

```js
let root_vegetables = ['potato', 'taro', 'sweet potato', 'carrot']
let trueRoots = root_vegetables.map(roots => (roots === 'carrot' || roots === 'sweet potato') ? 'True Roots' : 'Modified Roots')

console.log(trueRoots);
```